# Overriding GTK Window Close Event to Show a Message

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk, gtk#

I'm trying to override the Gtk.Window close event so that a Dialog is displayed to the user if a certain Boolean value is set.Inspite the Boolean Value being true my application Quits without showing the Dialog.I have tried printing out the Boolean value.It is correct.

```
protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
            Console.WriteLine (bval);
            if (bval == true) { 

                mynot notification=new mynot(this); 
                notification.Show (); 

            }
            else
            {
                Gtk.Application.Quit ();
                a.RetVal = true;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal handler return value should be true in the if-case (to stop the default handler from being invoked). In the else-case you should probably just return false to allow default handler to run and not call Quit() yourself.

Comment: Thanks .. i dont have access to the Mac system today,will take a look and get back tomorrow.

Comment: I cannot return false since the method is of void return type. But by putting  a.RetVal = true in the if case,it worked.Thanks

Comment: This works when running inside Xamarin Studio.But when running outside the app simply closes when it reaches the if condition.What can be going wrong?Please advice